# How to add automatic tag closing in gulp?

Tags: html, gulp

I create custom template engine and I need to add posibillity to close tags like `<img>` or `<link>` automatically through gulp. Is there any gulp module that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing HTML you do not need to close `<img>` and `<link>` tags.

> In HTML the `<link>` tag has no end tag.
>
> In XHTML the `<link>`tag must be properly closed.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

Comment: I know this perfectly but it will be special template engine and I need to close them by specific needs

Comment: So if you know this why should you do something different to the rest of the www?